# How to give an evidence in support of the arenium ion mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

> Outline the mechanistic steps involved in the arenium ion mechanism for
>   aromatic electrophilic substitution. Draw the energy profile diagram for the proposed mechanism. Give one evidence in support of the proposed mechanism.

I can solve the first two questions but I got confused about what the last question exactly asking for. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you've already drawn the energy profile diagram for your proposed mechanism , now you want to make sure that your reaction mechanism proceeds through the most stable transition state , ( Least activation energy ) and therefore , on the energy profile diagram , the peak occuring at the transition state should not be too high .Also you wanna make sure that your final products have energies lesser than the  reactants , because in that case , your $\Delta H$ would be $-ve$ and from the equation $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S $, there would be a greater chance your reaction moves forward.[image]

You also should have a look at [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/aromaticcompounds/reactions-benzene/v/electrophilic-aromatic-substitution)

Comment: Thanks But the last question that I am asking for carries only one mark. How can I answer it precisely?

Comment: @Sanu_012 You could explain it from the energy diagram , like I have , or you could point out in the mechanism that the carbocation formed during the mechanism is resonance stabilised and hence favours the forward reaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I gonna explain it in the carbocationic way.  It is worth one mark.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to answer the question...